# Find standard deviation of two different sets of numbers when combined

Tags: statistics

A set of 10 numbers has a mean of 10 and a standard deviation of 2.0 another set of 10 numbers have a mean of 4 and a standard deviation of 3.0 find the standard deviation of the 20 numbers

Answer (score 2):

suppose first set of number is {$x_1,x_2,x_3,......,x_{10}$}.since mean of this set is $10$.
so$$\dfrac{x_1+x_2+......+x_{10}}{10}=10\implies \mathbf {{x_1+x_2+......+x_{10}}=100}$$
To calculate Standard deviation we need deviation:
$$S.D.=\sqrt{\dfrac 1{N-1}\sum_ {i=1}^N(x_i-x)^2}$$
S.D.=$2$
$$4=\dfrac{{(x_1-10)}^2+{(x_2-10)}^2+...........{(x_{10}-10)}^2}{10-1}$$
$$4=\dfrac{(x_1^2+x_2^2+.......+x_{10}^2)-20({x_1+x_2+......+x_{10}})+1000}{9}$$
$$36={(x_1^2+x_2^2+.......+x_{10}^2)-(20\times 100)+1000}$$
$$\mathbf {1036={x_1^2+x_2^2+.......+x_{10}^2}}$$

similarly for second set {$x_{11},x_{12},.......x_{20}$}

Mean=$4$$${\mathbf{x_{11}+x_{12}+......+x_{20}}=40}$$
and from S.D.=$3$
$$\mathbf {x_{11}^2+x_{12}^2+......+x_{20}^2=241}$$

similarly we can calculate S.D. for these 20 numbers where those mean = 7

Now new set is {$x_1,x_2,...............,x_{20}$}
$$\mathbf{x_1+x_2+...............+x_{20}=140}$$
$$S.D.^2=\dfrac{(x_1-7)^2+(x_2-7)^2+........+(x_{20}-7)^2}{20-1}$$
$$S.D.^2=\dfrac{(x_1^2+x_2^2+....x_{10}^2+x_{11}^2.......+x_{20}^2)-14(x_1+x_2+....+x_{20})+20\times49}{20-1}$$
$$S.D.^2=\dfrac{(1036+241)-14(140)+20\times49}{20-1}$$
$$S.D.^2=\dfrac{(1036+241)-14(140)+20\times49}{20-1}$$
$$S.D.^2=\dfrac{1277-1960+980}{20-1}$$
$$S.D.^2=\dfrac{1277-1960+980}{20-1}$$
$$S.D.=3.954$$

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$$
\angles{x} = {1 \over 20}\sum_{n = 1}^{20}x_{n}
= {1 \over 20}\pars{10\,{\sum_{n = 1}^{10}x_{n} \over 10}
+ 10\,{\sum_{n = 11}^{20}x_{n} \over 10}}
= \half\pars{\angles{x}_{1} + \angles{x}_{2}}
$$
Similarly,
$$
\angles{x^{2}} = \half\pars{\angles{x^{2}}_{1} + \angles{x^{2}}_{2}}
$$
Then,
\begin{align}
&\angles{x^{2}} - \angles{x}^{2}
=
\half\pars{\angles{x^{2}}_{1} + \angles{x^{2}}_{2}}
-
{1 \over 4}\pars{\angles{x}_{1}^{2} + 2 \angles{x}_{1}\angles{x}_{2} + \angles{x}_{2}^{2}}
\\[3mm]&=
\half\pars{\angles{x^{2}}_{1} - \angles{x}_{1}^{2}}
+
\half\pars{\angles{x^{2}}_{2} - \angles{x}_{2}^{2}}
+
{1 \over 4}\pars{\angles{x}_{1}^{2} - 2 \angles{x}_{1}\angles{x}_{2} + \angles{x}_{2}^{2}}
\end{align}
$$\color{#0000ff}{\large%
\sigma
={\root{2} \over 2}\root{%
\sigma_{1}^{2} + \sigma_{2}^{2}
+ \half\pars{\angles{x}_{1} - \angles{x}_{2}}^{2}}}
$$
$$
\sigma = {\root{2} \over 2}\root{2^{2} + 3^{2} + \half\pars{10 - 4}^{2}}
=
{\root{62} \over 2} \approx 3.9370
$$